# Microsoft Graph SDK and SharePoint List items

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sdk, microsoft-graph-api

i'm trying to retrieve all items from a Tasklist in a SharePoint Projectsite with this function:

```
    public async Task<string> GetTasks(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string siteId, string listId)
    {
        string requestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/" + siteId + "/lists/" + listId + "/items?expand=fields";

        HttpRequestMessage hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);

        await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return content;
        }
        else
            throw new ServiceException(
                new Error
                {
                    Code = response.StatusCode.ToString(),
                    Message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                });
    }
```

but the response content is empty:

@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('xxxxxxxxxx.com%2Cde7be133-babf-4bc9-8e52-857657f8fdd6%2C379cb706-d430-4dfc-8347-f2c8bc92a38c')/lists('eca2429f-44b7-4d68-af81-f5e56fece3ab')/items","value":[]}

I don't understand why the response is empty. In the Graph Explorer it is returning the data. Can someone explain this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you query SharePoint `List Items`,  `Sites.Read.All` or `Sites.ReadWrite.All` permission scope needs to be specified.

According to [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference):

> `Sites.Read.All`  Read items in all site collections

Permission scopes per list type:

- SharePoint List: `Sites.Read.All`,`Sites.ReadWrite.All`
- SharePoint Library: `Files.Read.All`,`Files.ReadWrite.All`

Comment: That solved the problem. It was the missing permission. Strange that no error is returned, but Instead an empty collection. Thank you.