# Microsoft Graph SDK for Python: How to Get a SharePoint List?

Tags: python, azure, sharepoint, sdk, microsoft-graph-api

Preface, there are similar questions ([such as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49349577/microsoft-graph-sdk-and-sharepoint-list-items)) but these are different as the SDK for python doesn't seem to provide a manner to specify a domain name for the MS365 tenant.

I've created a client secret with adequate permissions to access the named resource. Below is my attempt and results:

```
from azure.identity.aio import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient

# Authentication details
tenant_id         = 'abcdefgh-1234-5678-9012-abcdefghijkl'
app_client_id     = 'abcdefgh-1234-5678-9012-abcdefghijkl'
client_secret_val = 'lmnop~abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzxy'

# SharePoint site ID and list name
site_id = 'mysite'
list_name = 'mylist'

# Build client
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, app_client_id, client_secret_val)
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
client = GraphServiceClient(credentials=credential, scopes=scopes)

# Collect data
req_list = client.sites.by_site_id(site_id).lists.by_list_id(list_name)
res = await req_list.get()
```

```
### outputs

ODataError: 
        APIError
        Code: 400
        message: None
        error: MainError(
            additional_data={}, 
            code='invalidRequest', 
            details=None, 
            inner_error=InnerError(
                additional_data={}, 
                client_request_id='23691144-abe3-467d-b160-21c7ae84473b', 
                date=DateTime(2024, 2, 5, 17, 57, 8, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 
                odata_type=None, 
                request_id='f69847e7-4f06-41b9-b2b2-5ce52e597364'
            ), 
            message='Invalid hostname for this tenancy', 
            target=None
        )
```

It seems to claim use of an invalid hostname for the tenancy, though I did not make use of a hostname. The SDK for python is quite new and I'm having a difficult time locating available methods and parameters for these objects.

Some links I needed to bookmark:

- [Get a SharePoint List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=python)https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=python
- [Microsoft Azure SDK for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/mgmt-datafactory-readme?view=azure-python)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I am the poster.

The solution seems to be that you can specify the tenant within the credential object:
`credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, app_client_id, client_secret_val, authority='mytenant.sharepoint.com')`

Doing this should move you past the provided issue. However, I now run into this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/22625